# Online messaging system

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm building a website at the moment and now i stand in a crossroad to chose which kind of messaging system to choose.

The website is build in asp.net, so using c# and other microsoft technologies i want to build a very simple messaging system between different users.

My question is how to do that, and what is the best way?

One option which i see is to use a database, to store the messages and then let the messaging page, every second refresh and perform code to retrieve the message, altho i tried it and i dont really like, because it isn't the proper way ... letting the page refresh and yeah retrieve the messages it is not very good.

But i dont really know the alternative i tried to search but didnt find any other possible solution only use of database and refreshing of the page.

My question is, what are any other possibilities to implement a very simple messaging system to a website, where for example 2 users can private message each other?

I dont need alot of explanation just some direction where to search ...

Thanks in advance for reading and replying to me, and for admins not to close the thread.

Comment: You are not talking about live chat or shoutbox isn't it ? So, you could code it in such a way that when user goes to any page, it should check the db for any new messages. If any new messages, show a notification to the user.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started.

[Simple Chat Application in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8307/Simple-Chat-Application-in-ASP-NET)

Here's another one that looks promising...

[LiveChat Starter Kit](http://livechatstarterkit.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and Ajax to get rid of the "refresh" page http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

Regarding if you should use DB or not. Its really up to you, to whatever you are comfortable with. It dosen't sound that you have a lots of requirement.

If I would do it by myself and its a micro project I think I just would store the messages in the HttpContext...

Comment: thanks a lot, and yes it isnt big project, just a small implementation so that users, can send to each other messages, but also if both of them online they will need to be able to chat, without a too big delay, if the person isn't online he should recieve message next time he enters the site